# Error while validating User Input in Python

Tags: python-3.8

I am having problem validating the user input (I am asking user if they wish to continue with the program of calculating factorial). The code is as follows: (User input validation is towards the end of the main function and I have not included the factorial function)

```py
def main():

    valid_inp = False
    usr_continue = True

    while usr_continue:

        while valid_inp == False:
            usr_inp = int(input('Please ENTER a number: '))

            if usr_inp < 0:
                print('ERROR, INVALID INPUT')

            else:
                valid_inp = True
                continue
        result = factorial(usr_inp)

        print(str(result) + '\n')

        con_inp = str(input('Would you like to continue ? '))

        if con_inp == 'Y' or con_inp == 'y':
            usr_continue

        elif con_inp == 'N' or con_inp == 'n':
            print('Goodbye...')
            break


main()
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with the validation? What is the actual behaviour, what is the expected behaviour etc...

Comment: The error is 'name error' when it tries to evaluate the if statement (if con_inp == ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function that only returns on valid input.  Use an exception handler to deal with bad integer input, then validate the integer is the range you want:

```py
from math import factorial

def get_nonnegative_integer(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt)) # bad input for int such as "abc" will raise ValueError
            if val >= 0:             # good input will be range-checked
                return val
            else:
                print('enter a number >= 0')
        except ValueError:
            print('invalid input for integer')
        
def main():
    while True:
        usr_inp = get_nonnegative_integer('Please enter a number: ')
        result = factorial(usr_inp)
        print(result)
        con_inp = input('Would you like to continue(Y/n)? ').upper() # default Yes
        if con_inp.startswith('N'):
            print('Goodbye...')
            break

main()
```